# What can cause a spot above my WiFi router's antenna?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, everyday-life, electronics, electrical-engineering

Lately a weird dark spot has appeared right above the antenna of my wifi router. It wasn't there before.

I have tried to wipe it and it got a little bit brighter but I don't think it's dust.

My guess would be mold or something else that is formed on the surface rather than charged particles flying towards the ceiling. (however I can't confirm, and I don't see why it would appear right there)

Is it even possible, that dust particles get charged by the antenna which makes them fly to the ceiling?

It's a basic, unmodified huawei router.

[image]

Comment: I think it was the heat generated by the router (Joule effect) that blackened the ceiling.

Answer (score 7):

Routers produce heat which warms the surrounding air causing it to rise. This airflow carries with it any dust, aerosols, or vapours which may be deposited or condense when they hit the ceiling. The problem is likely to be worse if there are regularly cooking fumes or people smoking.  The warm air might also encourage mold growth or if hot enough might thermally degrade the paint causing discoloration. Such discoloration above any heater is a [well known issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=black+marks+on+wall+above+heater&).